# Stream Google Drive Content to Chromecast

Tags: javascript, android, google-drive-api, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to build an app where the user can play google drive stored content locally and also cast it.

According to the google drive docs [Google Drive Developers Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), I have to make an http request like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

To play it locally I'm using [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), which is working really smooth, my issue is when I try to cast the content.

I think I have read all the docs referring to sender and receiver apps from the google cast developers site [Google Cast Developers Docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers), and I have not been able to cast content.

The receiver application is getting [403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmXMw.png) when I debug, cause it needs authentication. [403 Error on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxJ4L.png).

This error is caused because I'm not able to set the HTTP Headers "**Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN**", cause there is not option as far a I know to set the HTTP Headers.

I even opened an issue ticket to google [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112627081), where I requested that feature to be included in the generic receiver app, so that we don't have to host a receiver application just for that feature. And they answered this

"*You will need to write a receiver and provide a handler in playbackConfig.manifestRequestHandler that add the header. 
You will need to use the customData field of the load request to pass your token or any other data.*"

So, I tried to do what they to told me to do, and right now the sender app sends the Authorization token to the receiver app, but I'm stuck setting the token to the request header.

Here is the current code from the receiver app.

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
const castOptions = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();
const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

let playbackConfig = (Object.assign(new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig(), playerManager.getPlaybackConfig()));

playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
    cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD,
    request => {
    console.log("token: ", request.media.customData.token);

    playbackConfig.manifestRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
    requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
    requestInfo.headers = {};
    requestInfo.headers['Authorization'] = request.media.customData.token;
    };
  return request;
});
castOptions.playbackConfig = playbackConfig;
context.start(castOptions);
```

It would be great if somebody can help me, or guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many months of research, I change the way that I build the URL that is sent to cast, without needing and access token. Now I just send the file the I want to cast or download in the following format.(API key must have access to the files)

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID_OF_THE_FILE?alt=media&key=API_KEY

After that I received other error, which I reported to Google in this [Link](http://?alt=media&key=AIzaSyB6xr4maV5sr2pBLkgG36amrUpIjeIze98), and they found that there was a problem with the codec of my video ([Here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) is the list of supported codecs). So I had to re-encode all my videos. I used [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to do it, it even have a preset for chromecast. And finally I was able to cast my video from google drive.